# What is the purpose of this dummy variable variable and why program exits without it in c?

Tags: c

```
int main ()
{
    char c;
    int choice,dummy;
    do{
    printf("1. Print Hello\n2. Print World\n3. Exit\n");
    scanf("%d",&choice);
    switch(choice)
    {
        case 1 :
        printf("Hello\n");
        break;
        case 2:
        printf("World\n");
        break;
        case 3:
        exit(0);
        break;
        default:
        printf("please enter valid choice\n5");
    }
    printf("do you want to enter more?");
    scanf("%d",&dummy);
    scanf("%c",&c);
    }while(c=='y');
}
```

tried removing int dummy variable and dummy input, program exits without taking any character input. how is this helping the code to not to exit ?

Comment: Maybe give us the code that you're having issues with rather than vague description of what we must take out of it.

Answer (score 2):

The `scanf("%d",&dummy)` removes a newline so the subsequent `scanf("%c",&c);` works. Otherwise, it will take `\n` as its character.

The "extra" newline comes from the fact that it is left in the input stream by the original: `scanf("%d",&choice);`

---

To fix, remove the `dummy` related code and do:

```
scanf(" %c",&c);
```

Note the preceding space in the format. This tells `scanf` to skip over whitespace (which includes newlines).

---

The fully corrected code is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(void)
{
    char c;
    int choice;

    do {
        printf("1. Print Hello\n2. Print World\n3. Exit\n");

        scanf("%d", &choice);
        switch (choice) {
        case 1:
            printf("Hello\n");
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("World\n");
            break;
        case 3:
            exit(0);
            break;
        default:
            printf("please enter valid choice\n5");
        }

        printf("do you want to enter more?");
        scanf(" %c", &c);
    } while (c == 'y');

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's interesting that scanf("%d") leaves the newline in the buffer if there is an integer present, and removes it if there isn't. I knew the former, not the latter. Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: @pmacfarlane I don't use `scanf` in my own code. IMO, it's something horrible to inflict on newbies. So, I haven't memorized all its documentation. But, I do believe that it has to work for input like: `123x` and code: `scanf("%d",&num); scanf("%c",&i_want_x);` So, it couldn't absorb the _next_ char after `123` [even if it was `\n`] I tested various versions of the code (e.g. with `dummy`, without, and the corrected version). The explanation was the only one that made sense.

Comment: @pmacfarlane Actually, I think the semantics are that `%d` _will_ [implicitly] skip over leading whitespace [which includes newline]. So, the left over newline from `scanf("%d,&choice);` is the leading whitespace skipped by the subsequent `scanf("%d",&dummy);`. I didn't test it, but I believe the latter would return 0 for the count.

Comment: The `%d` will skip whitespace, and then fail when the first non-whitespace character is not a digit. So it's just a horrible hack to skip whitespace.

Answer (score 2):

Whoever wrote this doesn't understand how `scanf` format specifiers work.

The first call to `scanf` uses the `%d` format specifier.  This reads and discards any leading whitespace, then reads a decimal integer.  Assuming you pressed ENTER after typing in this integer, a newline character will be left in the input buffer.

The `%c` format specifier reads the first character in the input buffer but does *not* strip off trailing whitespace.  So without the prior call reading `dummy`, this will read the newline that was stuck in the input buffer previously into `c`.  That causes the comparison `c=='y'` to be false so the loop exits..

The extra call to `scanf` for `dummy` reads and discards the newline left in the input buffer and wait for an integer to be read.  Presumably, the user will enter `y` or `n` given the prompt, so that call to `scanf` will not read anything more and will return 0, indicating that nothing matched.  The following `scanf` then reads the `y` or `n`.

The proper way to handle this is to add a space before the `%c` format specifier to absorb leading whitespace instead of adding a "dummy" call:

```
printf("do you want to enter more?");
scanf(" %c",&c);
```